# What is the probability of choosing 13 cards from a deck of cards and having them all be hearts?

Tags: probability

What is the probability of choosing 13 cards from a deck of cards and having them all be hearts?

Im guessing I would have to do $\frac{13}{52} \times \frac{12}{51}\times...\times \frac{1}{40}$

I would like to know if there is a quicker way to do this.

Comment: You could write it as $\frac{1}{52\choose13}$ if you prefer!

Comment: That seemed pretty quick to me.  Okay, if by quick you mean succinctness in writing 13/52.... 1/40 = 13!/52...40 = 13!/(52!/39!)=13!39!/52! = 1/${52 \choose 13}$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\frac{\binom{13}{13}}{\binom{52}{13}} = \frac{13!\times 39!}{52!}
$$

Answer (score 1):

We must select all $13$ hearts while selecting $13$ of the $52$ cards in the deck.  Hence, the probability is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{13}{13}}{\dbinom{52}{13}}$$
which agrees with the answer you obtained.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to say this using counting is that there are 13 hearts and you want to choose all 13 of them in 13 draws. There are $\binom{13}{13}$ ways to do that. You want 0 of the other kinds of cards, and there are $\binom{39}{0}$ ways to do that. Finally, there are $\binom{52}{13}$ ways to draw 13 cards. Hence
$$\frac{\binom{13}{13}\binom{39}{0}}{\binom{52}{13}} = \frac{1}{\binom{52}{13}} = \frac{13!39!}{52!} = \frac{13\times12\times\dotsm\times 1}{52\times51\times\dotsm\times40}.$$